# report on single object salesforce

Tags: reporting

[image]

Hi friends i need your help to create this report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what little information you've provided; it looks to me that you want to create a Matrix report.

Matrix reports allow you to summarise by both rows and columns as you seem to want in this report, or, from the docs:

> Matrix reports are similar to summary reports but allow you to group and summarize data by both rows and columns. They can be used as the source report for dashboard components. Use this type for comparing related totals, especially if you have large amounts of data to summarize and you need to compare values in several different fields, or you want to look at data by date and by product, person, or geography. Matrix reports without at least one row and one column grouping show as summary reports on the report run page.

You can read more about report formats [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_changing_format.htm).

Comment: thanks for ur replay ,i replaced image ,please consider new,i need grand total also